# Tensorflow - feeding examples with different length

Tags: python, tensorflow

Each of my training examples is a list with different length.
I am trying to find a way to feed those examples into the graph.
Below is my attempt to do so by creating a list whose elements are placeholders with unknown dimensions.

```
graph2 = tf.Graph()
with graph2.as_default():
    A = list ()
    for i in np.arange(3):
        A.append(tf.placeholder(tf.float32 ,shape = [None,None]))
    A_size = tf.shape(A)

with tf.Session(graph=graph2) as session:
  tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
  feed_dict = {A[0]:np.zeros((3,7)) ,A[1] : np.zeros((3,2)) , A[2] : np.zeros((3,2)) }
  print ( type(feed_dict))
  B = session.run(A_size ,feed_dict=feed_dict)
print type(B)
```

However I got the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Shapes of all inputs must match: values[0].shape = [3,7] != values[1].shape = [3,2]
```

Any idea on how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation of `tf.placeholder`:

> **shape**: The shape of the tensor to be fed (optional). If the shape is not specified, you can feed a tensor of any shape.

You need to write `shape=None` instead of `shape=[None, None]`. With your code, Tensorflow doesn't know you are dealing with variable size input.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, I still get the same error as before.